# NestJS/TypeORM: Can custom repository extend from another custom repository which is inside another project?

Tags: microservices, nestjs, typeorm, npm-package

**ERROR**

> RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "UserQueryRepository" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

**VERSION**

- @nestjs/typeorm - 7.1.5
- @nestjs/common - 7.6.15
- @nestjs/core - 7.6.15
- nodejs - 12.21.0
- typeorm - 0.2.34

**DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM**

I have 2 projects: common & microservice-1

Common package has QueryService & QueryRepository and microservice-1 should extend from those files.

So in microservice-1 I have UserQueryService which extends from QueryService and UserQueryRepository which extends from QueryRepository.

*query.repository.ts*

```js
import { FindManyOptions, Repository } from 'typeorm';

export class QueryRepository<Entity> extends Repository<Entity> {
  findAll(options?: FindManyOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity[]> {
    return this.find(options);
  }
}
```

*query.service.ts*

```js
import { FindManyOptions } from 'typeorm';
import { QueryRepository } from '../repository';

export class QueryService<Entity> {
  constructor(protected readonly repository: QueryRepository<Entity>) {}

  findById(id: string): Promise<Entity> {
    return this.repository.findOne(id);
  }

  findAll(options?: FindManyOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity[]> {
    return this.repository.findAll(options);
  }
}
```

*user.query.repository.ts*

```js
import { QueryRepository } from '@project/common';
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from '../entity';

@EntityRepository(UserEntity)
export class UserQueryRepository
  extends QueryRepository<UserEntity> { // -> throws error
  // extends Repository<UserEntity> { // -> works without extending from common
}
```

*user.query.service.ts*

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { QueryService } from '@project/common';
import { UserEntity } from '../entity';
import { UserQueryRepository } from '../repository';

@Injectable()
export class UserQueryService extends QueryService<UserEntity> {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserQueryRepository)
    repository: UserQueryRepository,
  ) {
    super(repository);
  }

  getAllUsers(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return this.findAll();
  }
}
```

*user.module.ts*

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserController } from '../controller';
import { UserQueryRepository } from '../repository';
import { UserQueryService } from '../service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'user',
      password: 'pass',
      database: 'dbname',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserQueryRepository]),
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserQueryService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing adding your entities.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'postgres',
  url: 'postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/dbname',
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/entity/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
}),
```

PS: The path is from `dist` not `src`.

E.g: `__dirname + '/../user/entity/*.entity{.ts,.js}'`

Comment: Entities were missing only in this example, in real application it was all right. Problem occurs when we use common package where we have base repositories and we try to extend this common repositories in different microservices. We decided to switch to monorepo approach which also fixed this issue, because with monorepo we have shared dependencies for common modules.