# NestJS typeorm generic inheritance of Repository not working, this.function is not a function

Tags: typescript, oop, nestjs, typeorm

Iam trying to create a custom repository class that extends Repository so I can add custom log functions to be used from all repositories.
here is the code.

user.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(User)
        private readonly userRepository: BaseRepository<User>,
    ) {}

    async update(id: string, data: UpdateUserDto): Promise<UpdateResult> {
        return await this.userRepository.updateAndLog(id, data);
    }
}
```

BaseRepository.ts:

```
import { Repository, UpdateResult } from 'typeorm';


export class BaseRepository<T> extends Repository<T> {

  async updateAndLog(id: string, data: any): Promise<UpdateResult> {
    const entity = await this.findOne(id as any);
    const savedEntity = await this.update(id, data);
    // log the data here
    return savedEntity;
  }
}
```

so the output of the function is always:

```
[Nest] 13820  - 04/11/2023, 12:07:07 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] this.userRepository.updateAndLog is not a function
```

I read typeorm documentation about custom repositories: https://typeorm.io/custom-repository#how-to-create-custom-repository

StackOverflow:

- [How to do custom repository using TypeORM (MongoDB) in NestJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549668/how-to-do-custom-repository-using-typeorm-mongodb-in-nestjs)
- [NestJS/TypeORM: Can custom repository extend from another custom repository which is inside another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105168/nestjs-typeorm-can-custom-repository-extend-from-another-custom-repository-whic)

github: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2097

Yet nothing is working, is there something wrong with the following code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here comes from the `@InjectRepository(User)` : it injects an instance of `Repository` instead of the `BaseRepository` one.

I found [this repository](https://github.com/leosuncin/nest-typeorm-custom-repository/blob/master/src/task/task.module.ts) that provide a way to override the repository provided by the TypeORM module, but only for a specific entity.

However, we could adapt his approach to provide a generic repository instead :

```js
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [buildCustomRepositoryProvider<User>(User), UserService],
})
export class UserModule {
}
```

With a helper file like this :

```js
import { DataSource, Repository, UpdateResult } from 'typeorm';
import { Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import { getDataSourceToken, getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { EntityClassOrSchema } from '@nestjs/typeorm/dist/interfaces/entity-class-or-schema.type';

export interface BaseRepository<T> extends Repository<T> {
  this: Repository<T>;

  updateAndLog(id: string, data: any): Promise<UpdateResult>;
}

export function buildCustomRepositoryMethods<T>(): Pick<BaseRepository<T>, 'updateAndLog'> {
  return {
    async updateAndLog(id: string, data: any): Promise<UpdateResult> {
      const entity = await this.findOne({ where: { id: id as any } });
      const savedEntity = await this.update(id, data);
      // log the data here
      return savedEntity;
    },
  };
}

export function buildCustomRepositoryProvider<T>(entity: EntityClassOrSchema): Provider {
  return {
    provide: getRepositoryToken(entity),
    inject: [getDataSourceToken()],
    useFactory: (dataSource: DataSource) => {
      // Override the default repository with a custom one
      return dataSource.getRepository(entity).extend(buildCustomRepositoryMethods<T>());
    },
  };
}
```

Therefore, the `@InjectRepository(User)` will inject an instance of `Repository<User>` extended with the methods provided by the `BaseRepository` interface.

(Note : using the `extend` method here to create a custom repository as it's the recommended way since TypeORM 0.3, see [here](https://typeorm.io/custom-repository))

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, but isn't there a way to do it in a more generic way ?
the project has a lot of entities, so it would be a lot to create a repository for each entity.

Comment: Hello, I understand that could be a lot of classes to make. I edited my answer with a better approach accordingly

Comment: Hi! I wish you read it. It worked so far but now I need to extend this to a UserRepository, like create a UserRepository with all the functions already created in the BaseRepository. Is there anyway? Because you added this for only User, but what about all the others entities that I might have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this soluion, I am using this solution in my application

```
import { Type } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ObjectLiteral, Repository } from 'typeorm';

interface IDataService<T extends ObjectLiteral> {
  readonly repository: Repository<T>;
  findById: (id: string | number) => Promise<T | null>;
}

type Constructor<I> = new (...args: any[]) => I;

export function DataService<T extends ObjectLiteral>(
   entity: Constructor<T>,
): Type<IDataService<T>> {

   class DataServiceHost implements IDataService<T> {
     @InjectRepository(entity) public readonly repository: Repository<T>;

     public async findById(id: string | number): Promise<T | null> {
        return this.repository.findOneBy({ id } as any);
     }
   }
   return DataServiceHost;
}
```

Extend your service from DataService class,

```
class YourService extends DataService<YourDatasebaseEntity>(YourDatasebaseEntity)
```